# Как правильно создать JSON в javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

вот код html

```
<ul id="menu-to-edit" class="sortable-ui ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default wells"  data-depth="0" data-title='1' data-item-id="1">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells col-md-offset-1" data-depth="1" data-title='2' data-item-id="2" data-parent-id="1" >2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells col-md-offset-1" data-depth="2" data-title='3' data-item-id="3"  data-parent-id="1" >3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells" data-depth="0" data-title='4' data-item-id="4">4</li>
    </ul>
```

есть и другие дата атрибуты то я не пишу их что бы не захламлять (не в них суть)вот таким образом получаю дата атрибут

```
$( "#menu-to-edit li" ).each(function (i) {
    var model = $(this).data('model');// это те атрибуты которые не указал 
     var alias = $(this).data('alias');// это те атрибуты которые не указал 
     var depth = $(this).attr('data-depth');
     var title=$(this).data('title');
     var key = 'menu' + i;
     var addmenu = {title: title,  model: model,alias:alias,depth:depth};
     menu[key] = addmenu;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(menu));
```

получаю такой `json`

```
{
    "menu0":{
        "title":"1",
        "model":"Category",
        "alias":"catedory",
        "depth":"0"},
    "menu1":{
        "title":"2",
        "model":"Category",
        "alias":"catedory",
        "depth":"1"},
    "menu2":{
        "title":"3",
        "model":"Category",
        "alias":"catedory",
        "depth":"2"},
    "menu3":{
        "title":"4",
        "model":"Category",
        "alias":"catedory",
        "depth":"0",}
}
```

а хотелось бы, что бы получился  такой `json`  по уровню `depth`

```
 {
        "menu0":{
            "title":"1",
            "model":"Category",
            "alias":"catedory",
            "depthMenu":{
                "menu1":{
                    "title":"2",
                    "model":"Category",
                    "alias":"catedory",
                    "depthMenu":{
                    "menu2":{
                        "title":"3",
                        "model":"Category",
                        "alias":"catedory"}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "menu3":{
            "title":"4",
            "model":"Category",
            "alias":"catedory"}
    }
```

пытался сделать так

```
if(depth>0){
    var siblingItemDepht=depth-1;
}
```

но дальше не могу сообразить что сделать.

Comment: у тебя нет отношения родитель-потомок. Не к чему привязаться, чтоб выстроить структуру со вложенностью.......например почему `menu1` является потомком `menu0`, а не `menu3`? Нет связи.. Как только у тебя появится доп. параметр, например `parent`, в котором будет указан родитель - тогда можно будет построить

Comment: Вы хотите создать древовидную структуру объектов. Для этого Вы должны определиться с тем, как находить родителя для данного элемента меню.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я предполагал так найти первый элемент у которого depth на 1 меньше чем у вложенного таки образом вот и родитель. Для этого и пытаюсь сделать так `if(depth>0){
    var siblingItemDepht=depth-1;
}` да и чуть чуть отредактировал (код html не было видно)

Comment: @Igor в принципе пояснил предыдущему комментатору.

Comment: @Sergalas то есть все элементы первого уровня окажутся под первым нулевым?

Comment: @Igor хотелось  что бы так получилось

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо если я узнаю id родителя (ну пусть будет data-id?)

Comment: @Sergalas ну классика построения дерева какова: имеются id - индивидуальный номер ветки и parent_id - который указывает на номер родителя. Если parent_id = 0 или отсутствует, значит это самый первый элемент в иерархии. А дальше рекурсией уже строится дерево, на основе parent_id. Вот и тебе нужно определить кто кем у тебя является, дополнить соответсвующими данными (можешь написать и `data-parent-id` если нужно) и уже на основе него всё сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в теории я понял для чего parent_id нужен я не понимаю как такое реализовать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я поправил помоги реально не выруливаю какую рекурсию надо сделать что бы пошло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так.

Поменял немного ключ (key), привязал его к data-item-id, иначе тяжело поиск родителя сделать. Из-за этого нумерация начинается с 'menu1', а не с 'menu0'.

```js
var menu = {};
$( "#menu-to-edit li" ).each(function (i) {
 var model = $(this).data('model'); 
 var alias = $(this).data('alias');
 var depth = parseInt($(this).data('depth'));
 var title = $(this).data('title').toString();
 var key = 'menu' + $(this).data('item-id');
 var addmenu = { title: title, model: model, alias:alias };

 var parentKey = 'menu' + $(this).data('parent-id');
 var parent = menu[parentKey];
 if (parent) {
   for (var j = depth; j > 1 && parent; j--) {
     parent = parent.depthMenu;
   }
   if (parent) parent.depthMenu = addmenu;
 }
 else {
   menu[key] = addmenu;
 }
});
$('#result').html(JSON.stringify(menu, "", 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<ul id="menu-to-edit" class="sortable-ui ui-sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default wells" data-model="Category" data-alias="category" data-depth="0" data-title='1' data-item-id="1">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default wells col-md-offset-1" data-model="Category" data-alias="category" data-depth="1" data-title='2' data-item-id="2" data-parent-id="1" >2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default wells col-md-offset-1" data-model="Category" data-alias="category" data-depth="2" data-title='3' data-item-id="3"  data-parent-id="1" >3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default wells" data-model="Category" data-alias="category" data-depth="0" data-title='4' data-item-id="4">4</li>
</ul>

<hr/>

<pre id='result'></pre>
```

Comment: вот попытался реализовать под свои нужды https://codepen.io/sirgalas/pen/dWgPvx, что я сделал не так?